# Google Appengine: How to schedule a task to run once at a time of the day

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I am faced with a situation where I want a user to perform an action and **have the option to revert the action before the next 24 hours**, else the action would be executed. The only solution I have been able to come up with is to use a **Cron Job** and schedule it for a particular time of the day and in the Job I would check for all actions that their scheduled time has passed then execute them. But the action does not happen very often and thus having a Cron job running does not appear to be a good solution to me as I am not even sure of the cost implication.

What I want to do is that whenever a user clicks on the action a Job should be scheduled and once that action is executed the schedule should be cancelled. Is it possible to do this with Cron Job? If no what alternative does GAE provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request is scheduled by a cron job it's handled as one normal request, from the quota/billing perspective. I suppose your applications gets much more requests per day, so plus one request shouldn't be a matter, unless your application is quite heavyweight.

I'd prefer cron over deferred tasks, because the latter is more convoluted. A cron job most likely would query the datastore then do something or not. It's easier to keep track or manage the state of the datastore than keep track of deferred tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

(1) Run a cron-job once per hour (for example). Execute all actions that have more than 24 hours since time of their creation.

(2) When an action is stored, create a task using a [DeferredTask API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/). Give this task a name (e.g. an ID of an action), in case you need to cancel it. Add this task to a queue with a delay of 24 hours. Java example:

```
 Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();

  // Wait 24 hours to run
  queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(new MyTask())
      .name(taskName).etaMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```